# PHP Bug? With Class?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<?php class Video { protected $_test; } ?>
```

and when I try to include the file containing this code I've got that error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in ../classes/Video.class.php on line 1
```

What's wrong? I don't understand.

Comment: Are you sure you're running PHP 5?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you're still running PHP 4, which doesn't know the `protected` keyword.

An update to PHP 5 would be a good idea.